# Updating of data of provider doesn't reflect to next page in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to update data of provider and use them in the next page, but the data is going to be null.

Here is my model and provider:

```
class User {
  String? firstName;
  String? lastName;

  User({this.firstName, this.lastName});

  update({String? firstName, String? lastName}) {
    this.firstName = firstName ?? this.firstName;
    this.lastName  = lastName  ?? this.lastName;
  }
}
```

```
class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  late User user;

  void updateUser({String? firstName, String? lastName}) {
    user.update(firstName : firstName, lastName : lastName);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

And this is the page which I use `updateUser` method written above:

```
class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {
  ...
  Future<void> updateUser(UserProvider provider) async {
    provider.updateUser(
      firstName : _firstNameController!.text,
      lastName  : _lastNameController!.text
    );
  }
  ...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final UserProvider userProvider = Provider.of(context, listen : true);
    ...
    MyButton(
      label     : 'Submit',
      onPressed : () async {
        updateUser(userProvider)
          .then((_) => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second_page');
      }
    )
    ...
```

Then this is where I use it:

```
class SecondPage exntends StatelessWidget {
  ...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final UserProvider userProvider = Provider.of(context, listen : true);
    final User user = userProvider.user!;
    print('user.firstName : ${user.firstName}'); // this is for check if it exists
    ...
```

(These are simplified for ease of thinking, so there might be some mistakes, but please don't mind.)

Why is it still null? Please tell me how can I fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to initialise `user` in `UserProvider`.

`UserProvider` should be look like..

```
class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  User user = User();

  void updateUser({String? firstName, String? lastName}) {
    user.update(firstName : firstName, lastName : lastName);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Or if you are make sure you called `updateUser` before the usage of `user`, then you code should be look like...

```
class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  late User user;

  void updateUser({String? firstName, String? lastName}) {
    user = User(firstName : firstName, lastName : lastName);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**Edited**

Introduce one more function to set the initial data for `user`.

```
class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  late User user;

  void updateUser({String? firstName, String? lastName}) {
    user.update(firstName : firstName, lastName : lastName);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setUser(User user){
    this.user = user;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I have other fields for User model, and some of them are not nullable, so I'm awkward to initialize because it needs space a lot. In addition, I assign data before I update it. So I though I don't have to initialize, but is it needed?

Comment: Yes, you must initiate if you are referencing the variable with `late`

Comment: If you can't prefil the user details, then fetch the data and set it to the `user`.

Comment: Look at my recent edit, which provides the function to set the initial `user` data.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I tried to set initial data for user, but it's still null. So I'm going to try the way you showed for me next. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Update `updateUser` method in  `UserProvider` class like below.

```
 void updateUser({String? firstName, String? lastName}) {
    user.firstName = firstName;
    user.lastName = lastName;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it seems it doesn't work...